# I have an issue in calculating stats developers using devockpit plugin and jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have an issue in calculating stats for developers using jenkins, sonar, sonar runner and sonar plugin "Developer Cockpit"

Config : 
http://screencast.com/t/AEIz6bNaB3o

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but     found: 2
ERROR: 
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Build step 'Lancer une analyse Sonar autonome' marked build as failure
Saut de l'analyse sonar suite à un mauvais status de construction FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Your error mentions `Lancer une analyse Sonar autonome` and `selectOne()`. If this is a custom function, providing its code would help to find the error.

Comment: No, it is not a custom function.

Comment: Lancer une analyse Sonar autonome (in french) = 
http://docs.codehaus.org/download/attachments/227052875/add-build-step.png?version=1&modificationDate=1350911559683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Developer Cockpit plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/developer-tools/developer-cockpit/) is a commercial plugin developed by [SonarSource](http://www.sonarsource.com). So if you want support on this plugin, [please contact the commercial support mailing list](http://www.sonarsource.com/get-contact/) (you must have asked for a trial license to test this plugin, so you know who to contact to get support).